# MySQL Workbench not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mysql-workbench

When I upgraded the ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04,MySQL Workbench not show in the system.Then I installed the MySQL Workbench community & run it then.It gives a below error.How can I resolve it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Visit this URL, choose the OS and there is a package for Ubuntu 20 ! it is running smoothly but i have a problem in creating the new user apart from root still have to figure it out, but it is okay for me now i can use the different schemas in the root.

Comment: The download link contains a deb package while the asker have installed a snap package. Debs don't have such limitations. If you install the deb package from this link, remember to remove the snap package.